# SSH download file from web server

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal, scp

I need to do a backup on a website, but I need to download *locally* to a folder on my hard drive.

Example: `scp name.zip  -> MyMac/Documents/Backup`

This can be done via shell, Terminal, etc.  What is the best method for this?

Answer (score 5):

`scp [user@]vps.example.com:name.zip ~/Documents/Backup/` will do what you want.

The `scp(1)` manual page has the details, but the syntax `scp ${from} ${to}`, where `from` and `to` are of the form: `${host}:${path}` or `${path}`.

You might also be interested in `sftp`, which is an FTP-like interactive experience, rather than the command-line `scp` experience; `sftp vps.example.com` will get you going there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.i try this scp vps.example.com:name.zip ~/Documents/Backup/ but not works

Comment: You will have to include the error message to have a hope of anyone else telling you why.  Did you *literally* type `vps.example.com` in there?  You can't just copy and paste my example, you need to use the name of your system and all.

Comment: yes,i use my host and username..but "Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: It could by the file has the wrong permissions, you got your login details wrong, the server only allows key based logins, or they have disabled scp.  The last is very unlikely, though, because scp is very little different to `ssh vps.example.com cat /path/to/file` and all.

Comment: In case it is unclear, you should run the command on your local machine.